# Redirect to a new domain, same path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to ensure a canonical domain in a `before_filter` of my application controller (Rails 3.2). If a `GET` request comes in on a supported domain, but not the canonical domain, then we should redirect to the exact some path and protocol, but on a swapped out domain.

```
before_filter :ensure_correct_domain
def ensure_correct_domain
  if Rails.env.production? && request.get? && request.host != Settings.domain
    redirect_to host: Settings.domain
  end
end
```

This code mostly works, but I've found it fails on a formatted path. Here's what happens:

- GET http://supporteddomain.com/some_path.xml
- Redirects to: http://canonicaldomain.com/some_path

Sadly, I lose the extension, and I'm not sure why. I'm also worried theres more edge cases I haven't stumbled into.

How can I cleanly replace the host of the URI *only* of the current requested URL and have it work in *all* cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a hash to `redirect_to`, it calls `url_for` with the hash. It looks like you need to add `format: "xml"` (or whatever) to the hash for formatted paths. A perhaps cleaner (relatively speaking) alternative would be to simply construct a URL using the canonical domain and issue a `redirect_to` using that string. That string will be used without further processing if it begins with a protocol.

For 3.2 onward I think this should work, but I haven't tested it.

```
if Rails.env.production? && request.get? && request.host != Settings.domain
  redirect_to "#{request.protocol}#{Settings.domain}#{request.fullpath}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems awesome as it avoids parsing a reconstituting the path.